# Grep not working inside of script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to write a script that takes a string and then looks for all instances of that string a a file. When I run the command outside of the script it runs perfectly but if I try to run it in the script is says that the file doesn't exist. Here is my code

```
    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "Please enter an argument"
    else
          $result=`grep $1 Sales.csv`
          echo $result
    fi
```

And yes the file is called Sales.csv. I would have thought it was something to do with the format of the file but the command works outside of the script which is why I'm confused

Edit: Should have mentioned that I'm running the linux from virtualBox

Comment: It should be `result=$(grep $1 Sales.csv)`.  Putting the `$` in front of the word result makes it the output of the variable and not the actual variable itself.

Comment: You do not need to set a variable here. `grep $1 Sales.csv` will suffice. If you wish you can pipe it to a file

Comment: @Panther I will be piping it to another script down the line but I wanted to use the echo to make sure it was working

Comment: @Terrance Ah ok thanks, unfortunately it is still telling me that the file does not exist. I should mention that I'm using virtualBox in case that might cause any issues, I'll add an edit to my OP

Comment: Ah, you would need to have the full path to the file then.  `/some/path/Sales.csv`

Comment: Yes that's seems to have done something all right. The script now runs but is unresponsive but hopefully that's an issue I can go away and sort out myself easily enough. Thanks for your help

Comment: @HughO'Brien As Panther says, you don't need to assign to a variable here. If you don't pipe or redirect the output of `grep`, it shows in your terminal, where you can inspect it. But can you **[edit]** your question to add some missing details? How are you running the script? Can you give an actual example of a specific command you have run to use it? For example, maybe you are running `./my-script foo bar`. Or perhaps you are running `./my-script 'foo bar'`. Of course it's unlikely you're using either of those exact commands, but please do include at least one exact command you *are* using.

Answer (score 4):

When assigning a variable you just put whatever you want as the variable minus the `$`.  Putting the `$` in front of the variable makes it the output of the variable.  Since the variable isn't defined in the script yet the line should be:

```
result=$(grep $1 /some/path/to/Sales.csv)
```

Then calling the variable next like:

```
echo $result
```

Hope this helps!